# \answerline to the right of a question

Tags: positioning, exam

using `exam` class.  I want the answerline on the same line as the question, to be used in mid-sentence actually.

I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Write hello  \answerline[hello] to your mother
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your problem that `\answerline` is placed a line below `\question` but you want both of them to be in the same line? (If so, please state it, if not, please tell us your problem to be solved.) (A `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}` before `\answerline` could help, but there is probably some better solution, if that is indeed the issue here.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your request, as well as provided some more modifications (using `\answerline*`) to remove the number typesetting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove the separation by patching `\answerline` with [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\par\nobreak\vskip\answerskip}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Write hello  \answerline[hello]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This will remove the skip for *all* `\answerline`s. Alternatively, on a case-by-case basis, you can set `\answerskip` carefully:

```
\question Write hello%
\setlength{\answerskip}{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}
\answerline[hello]
```

---

Further modifications are also possible. The following MWE incorporates the above changes, but also provides a starred variant of `\answerline` that removes the number before the answer and allows for things to follow `\answerline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\par\nobreak\vskip\answerskip}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}{\fi \par}{\fi}{}{}% Remove line break after \answerline
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\oldanswerline}{\answerline}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\answerline}{s o}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\def\@queslevel{\relax}}% \answerline*
    {}% \answerline
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\oldanswerline[{}]}% \answerline
    {\oldanswerline[#2]}% \answerline[..]
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Write hello  \answerline[hello] to your mother
\question Write hello  \answerline*[hello] to your mother
\question Write hello  \answerline[hello] to your mother
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) provides the means to store macros with optional arguments created using `\newcommand`.

Comment: will it still print the answers when I use \printanswers?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Yes. Try it!

Comment: Nice solution. How do I turn this on in one part of my document and then back to the normal behavior for the rest of it?

Comment: @me: Put the `usepackage` commands in the top (before `start document`), then put the rest inside `\begingroup` and `\par\endgroup`. (But it adds an `xparse/redefine-command` warning).

Comment: @Werner, This still includes the question number (or letter) before the answerline and it's still not quite in line with the text. Can that be fixed?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the \fillin environment instead.  See *5.6 Fill in the blank questions* of [Using the exam document class](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Write hello \fillin[hello] to your mother
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```