# \answerline to the right of a question with dot line between answer line and question

Tags: exam

I see a nice feature [\answerline to the right of a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82152/answerline-to-the-right-of-a-question).
The answer is put to the right of a question. What I want is:

1. the number before the answer line should be removed, because I think the number before answer line is redundant.
2. dotted line between the question end and the answer.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code from [Werner's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82183/15925) to the other question, you can put a `\leaders` command in the replacement text that was removing the vertical skip.

`\leaders` takes some box and copies it enough times to fill up some specified horizontal space.  So here is one version: we make a box containing a dot with some space around it, we ask the sequence of boxes to fill up an aggressively stretchable horizontal space of `0pt plus 1filll`.  This will squeeze out the other stretchable space on the line before the answer material, pushing it to the right and filling the intervening space with a line of dots.

For removing the number, we just note that Werner's code already provided a command `\answerline*` command, so we may use that when we wish to suppress numbers.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\par\nobreak\vskip\answerskip}% <search>
  {\leaders\hbox{\hskip0.2em .\hskip0.2em}\hskip 0pt plus 1filll}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}{\fi \par}{\fi}{}{}% Remove line break after \answerline
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\oldanswerline}{\answerline}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\answerline}{s o}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\def\@queslevel{\relax}}% \answerline*
    {}% \answerline
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\oldanswerline[{}]}% \answerline
    {\oldanswerline[#2]}% \answerline[..]
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question Write hello \answerline*[hello] to your mother
  \question Write hello \answerline[hello] to your mother
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks for the answer, though the thanks come a litter later. I just mark your post as a good answer, thank you again.